# Cakephp: add a model to $uses at runtime

Tags: php, cakephp, controller

I need to write a modular function that could work with any kind of controller. I need, at runtime, to do something like.

```
$tools=array("a","b","c");
foreach($tools as $tool{
   ...
   //here there should be something like add_to_$uses($tool)
   $this->{$tool}->find();
```

Obviously simply adding the item to `$this->uses` doesn't work. How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: A "modular function that could work with any kind of controller" sounds like [Components](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html) a lot.

Comment: no it's something a bit different, i'm using an heavily reworked version of cakephp and i have particular necessities, it's not that easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is `loadModel` method.

```
$tools=array("a","b","c");
foreach($tools as $tool) {
   // ...
   $this->loadModel($tool);
   $this->{$tool}->find();
}
```

More info in [CakePHP's Book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/992/loadModel)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to load a model to a controller at runtime. Basically, you need to add all the models you might ever use to the controller's `$uses` array.

However, if the models are associated to another model in your uses array, then you can bind them at runtime in the controller:

```
$this->Model1->bind(
    'hasOne' => array(
        'Model2'
    )
);
```

You can change the `hasOne` to the type of relationship for your model. You can also add as many models as you want.

The converse of this is `unbind`.

Comment: It works. I use this practice in my projects where I don't need a certain model association all the time.  However, I am not sure that it will accomplish what you are trying to do.  Good luck!